# Linker yells that my function from other file is not defined

Tags: c, makefile, include

I have a function `int get_token();` defined in file `scanner.c` and I have a declaration of it in header file `scanner.h`. Now I included this header file in another header called `precedence.h` and at last I included `precedence.h` in `precedence.c` file where I want to call my function `get_token();`.

When I call this function, calling `make` throws following error:

```
gcc precedence.c t_stack.c -o expr
/tmp/ccNgwuFu.o: In function `main':
precedence.c:(.text+0x730): undefined reference to `get_token'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'expr' failed
make: *** [expr] Error 1
```

and this is my Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CFILES=precedence.c t_stack.c
HFILES=precedence.h t_stack.h token.h error.h

all: expr

expr: $(CFILES) $(HFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFILES) -o $@
```

I have tried including scanner.h along with precedence.h, also changing Makefile.

I'm just little experienced with C programming.

Comment: You defined `get_token` in `scanner.c`.  Then you proceeded to try to link your program with no reference to `scanner.c`.  You need to add `scanner.c` to your `Makefile`, compile it, and link with it.  Or, alternatively, don't use `get_token`.

Comment: I was editing wrong makefile :D LOL 
thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker fails to address function `get_token` because it seems to be *defined* in a file `scanner.c`, which is not passed to the compiler. Your include files probably just *declare* this function (i.e. provide a function prototype without body/implementation).

You'd probably write:

```
gcc precedence.c t_stack.c scanner.c -o expr
```